# Get data from a exe file in c++

Tags: visual-c++

I have a file.exe file that I need to run in the c++ file of visual studio. Now this exe file takes data from a text file and stores it in suitable variable lists. I need to access these exe file's list variables later on in my cpp file. Can this be done? Or, do I need to write the code that does the work done by the exe file?

Comment: The description is too confusing. It is unclear what you really want to do

Comment: Maybe you can use a .dll file in order to access your functions which read the file. I'm not sure wether you can access the variables in your library but you can write accessor-functions to get and set them.